# Capturing Words in HTML tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to know what is the most regular optimized to capture keywords in an HTML text expression.
Note that I am using PHP.

I have a piece of HTML code like this:

```
...
<li><span class="fl">
Dish</span>
<div class="oflow">
<span class="1F4446484E1FCB4FC3C21FC04AC6C21E232020211F underline">
pasta</span>
, <span class="1F4446484E1FCB4FC3C21FC04AC6C21E23202A251F underline">
rice</span>
, <span class="1F4446484E1FCB4FC3C21FC04AC6C21E2320202B1F underline">
potatoes</span>
</div>
</li>
...
```

I want to select the available dishes (pasta, rice and potatoes), knowing that the only word that is always the same is "Dish" and that there's always a span between each keyword that I would recover.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/, http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php, http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/php-domdocument-tutorial/

Comment: are the oflow or fl classes always the same and are these only used for what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    var $aDishes = explode(',', strip_tags($sHtml));
?>
```